# Warnings about partition tables on /dev/md? during preseed installation. (Debian Lenny)

Tags: debian, software-raid, debian-lenny, preseed

I'm setting up an environment to install many Lenny machines at once and I need to avoid any dialog with the process, corner cases aside.  One thing that consistently troubles me is that after my preseeded disk recipe creates Linux RAID-1 devices, the installer warns me about how the kernel could not re-read the partition table on each MD device.   When I do a manual installation and try to use debconf-get-selections to preseed another installation, it seems to ignore the whole preseed file altogether.  But reading through those selections, I couldn't find anything that seemed to suggest it would select "OK" on this extraneous warning.

Comment: I haven't tried on Lenny, but in Debian Squeeze preseed+raid is totally broken. I would guess you might need to work around that.

Comment: Well... that's really bad.

Comment: Yeah, the partman preseed stuff could use some extra love. preseed is pretty awesome and I really appreciate the work they've done on it.

Comment: dimmer, In case you're curious, I copied /dev/mem and searched for the warning message and from that I was able to discover the correct preseed answer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I will have to give that a try next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else stuck on this issue, you can use the following line in your preseed file:

```
d-i partman/exception_handler_note note
```

But you'll want to be aware of the implied risks.